# Can't load all friend Facebook API python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook API. I try the below code but it shows only 27 friends in my list friend(I have about 200). Why? Thanks for your help.

```
import facebook
token = 'my_token'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
friends = graph.get_connections(id='me', connection_name='friends')
numberOfFriends = len(friends['data'])
print numberOfFriends
for fr in friends['data']:
    print fr['name'] +" "+ fr['id']
```

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/issues/191

Comment: I get access token from graph api explorer. I don't have any app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only friends who authorized your app will show up. If you did not select your own app in the explorer, it will be the friends who authorized the explorer app with the user_friends permission.